# define the targetSdkVersion depending on the device

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I have defined in my manifest  `android:targetSdkVersion="15"` and I would like to test with a device with `API level` equal to `17`.

The `minSdkVersion` is set to 15.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

I know it will work since minSdkVersion is set to a lower version than the device's one but my question is should I change the targetVersion whenever I change the device ? Isn't the `targetSdkVersion` supposed to be always equal to the one of the device I am testing with as it is said in the reference

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html ?

Comment: The target version and the min SDK version are there when you release to general public, these wont change Dynamically as per device. Certain code functions are dependent on the version you choose.

Comment: In brief, NO. You don't have to change target SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't change the target version with every device, but with every new API level that is released.

As the webpage that you've already posted states:

> As Android evolves with each new version, some behaviors and even
>   appearances might change. However, if the API level of the platform is
>   higher than the version declared by your app's targetSdkVersion, the
>   system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app
>   continues to work the way you expect.

and a few lines further:

> To maintain your application along with each Android release, you
>   should increase the value of this attribute to match the latest API
>   level, then thoroughly test your application on the corresponding
>   platform version.

Every new API contains new features, but will also deprecate old ones; some may even get removed completely! So devices running with a higher API level might not support the same features anymore that you used in your app, which forces them to enable compatibility mode to once again be able to run the app properly.

In short, no, your `targetSdkVersion` should just be as high as the highest API goes. The `minSdkVersion` should of course be as low as possible, and you should try to avoid using `maxSdkVersion`, as that one will decrease the mobility of your app over time.
Even if your `minSdkVersion` is 1 and the `targetSdkVersion` is 19, new devices won't have to enable compatibility mode to run the app.